# PYTEST: how to set "DEBUG" and "INFO" log output levels at the same time?

Tags: python, pytest

The trouble with the documentation at pytest, I don't understand where you can see the possible values + I need to see ALL the output in the log at ALL. How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Pytest uses the builtin logging module in the background. When you check the [Logging Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#levels), you can find your desired logging levels.

Each higher level includes all the lower ones aswell. So set it as high as you want, then all of the other should be logged aswell.